# getting intellisense to show properties in markup for a custom server control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a custom control that inherits from **UserControl**, and I can't get it's properties to show in intellisense.  For example, I have a property:

```
public string Title;
```

but if I start typing:

```
ff:myControl Tit...
```

Nothing shows up (like I think it should). I have tried adding attributes like **Browsable**, **EditorBrowsable**, etc, but nothing is seeming to work - what am I forgetting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am dumb.  Just forgot the:

```
get;set;
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to use xml comments to your properties?
or this is the base class properties?
Anyway, i don't think that xml comments intellisense are supported on the markup, and "Browsable" attribute is only determine whether display the property on the properties window, and "EditorBrowsable" determine which window will be use to edit the property.